# Images in a rails app not getting pushed to git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have a simple app that I push to github. It contains images under `public/images` folder.  Images are of extension `.png`

I've pushed the code onto git hub and it got pushed w/out any errors.  However, when I go to my repository from the browser...I do not see the images folder under public.

Why are they being ignored?

My .gitignore file contains:

```
log/*.log
tmp/*
tmp/**/*
doc/api
doc/app
db/*.sqlite3
*.swp
* ̃
.DS_Store
```

For some unholy reason, it is not showing up in my navigation either. but IS showing in the terminal...
[image]

Comment: Are your files committed locally? Can you double check?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly fixed it but something did. I ran git add . and it added displayed 'created' for all images. then I tried to commit them using `-am` but that resulted in error `Not a git repository`. So I just closed all terminals...opened again. commited and pushed. now all is well.

Comment: Gedit only shows the files it can open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest doing the following:

```
git add public/images/*
git commit -a -m "Adding images"
git push origin
```

I hope this helps!